# Sorting an ArrayList whose first half is already relatively ordered

Tags: sorting, arraylist, big-o, time-complexity, timsort

I am currently trying to optimize a sorting algorithm for an Arraylist of 100 items. The thing is that my list has the invariant that the first half of its items are always in relative order to themselves...

(i.e. {1,1,4,5,6,2,1,11,4,3}, because the first 5 items are relatively ordered).

In order to take advantage of this feature I'm considering only sorting the right half of the list and then merging the two halves in order. My reasoning is that by only sorting half the list then merging, I can achieve a time complexity of (m lg(m) + n) where m = n / 2. Does this make the big-Oh complexity any better than O(nlg(n)) or would (m lg(m) + n) end up reducing to O(nlg(n)) anyways?

Any insight regarding the big-Oh of this problem or the most efficient approach to this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not just use timsort?

Comment: Most library sorts are already optimized for partially ordered arrays. In particular, the Java one is.  Not to mention that 100 is an incredibly small number to worry about. This will take a few microseconds on any reasonable modern hardware. What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: So... What you are asking is mergesort? Also, in your example, the 1,3, and 4 in the right half of your list will need to be put into the left half thus causing all the other elements in the left half to be resorted... Maybe you'll need quicksort then and your partition position is half the list?

Comment: I would use Timsort if i was just looking for the most effective solution, however the point of this assignment is the analysis on the time-complexity of my sorting algorithm more than the solution, and I wanted to be able to describe the specific worst-case run-time with the half sorted invariant. 1, 3, and 4 are in the right half in the example, but I suppose what i was trying to illustrate is that in implementing a mergesort, you wouldn't need to make any recursive step on the left half of the array, only the right and then one final merge to sort the two sides together.